# What is optimal API to scan Google Cloud BigTable data in Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-cloud-bigtable

I see there are 2 hbase table-scanning APIs in Google Cloud's sample code:

**1) using google.cloud module bigtable object**
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigtable/hello/main.py

```
from google.cloud import bigtable
client = bigtable.Client(project=project_id, admin=True)
instance = client.instance(instance_id)
table = instance.table(table_id)
partial_rows = table.read_rows(...)
partial_rows.consume_all()
for row_key, row in partial_rows.rows.items():
```

**2) using google.cloud module bigtable and happybase objects**
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigtable/hello_happybase/main.py

```
from google.cloud import bigtable
from google.cloud import happybase
client = bigtable.Client(project=project_id, admin=True)
instance = client.instance(instance_id)
connection = happybase.Connection(instance=instance)
table = connection.table(table_name)
for key, row in table.scan():
```

**Which of these 2 mechanisms is the recommended approach for scanning BigTable?**

**Also, are they suitable for using from PySpark ?**

Answer (score 1):

Either one of these libraries can be made to work with PySpark, however we generally recommend our native API (the first example) rather than HappyBase, if you are building a new application.

We provide the HappyBase adapter for Google Cloud Bigtable as a convenience for developers looking for an easier path to migrate existing workloads using HappyBase from an HBase deployment over to Google Cloud Bigtable.